# How to create a tables with variable length with string-like keys in lua

Tags: lua

I have a file database. Inside that file I have something like:

```
DB_A = ...
DB_B = ...
.
.
.
DB_N = ...
```

I would like to parse the data and group them in lua code like this:

```
data={}

-- the result after parsing a file
 data={
    ["DB_A"] = {...},
    ["DB_B"] = {...},
    .
    .
    .
    ["DB_N"] = {...}
 }
```

In other words, is it possible to create a table inside a table dynamically and assign the key to each table without previously knowing what will be the names of the key (that is something I can figure out after parsing the data from a database).

Comment: Can't you massage the input file to generate Lua code that can then be loaded in Lua?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Just as a note, I am using Lua 5.3.5; also, I apologize that my code resembles C more than Lua!)

Iterating through your input file line-by-line--which can be done with the Lua `FILE*`'s `lines` method--you can use `string.match` to grab the information you are looking for from each line.

```
#!/usr/bin/lua

local PATTERN = "(%S+)%s?=%s?(%S+)"

local function eprintf(fmt, ...)
    io.stderr:write(string.format(fmt, ...))
    return
end

local function printf(fmt, ...)
    io.stdout:write(string.format(fmt, ...))
    return
end

local function make_table_from_file(filename)
    local input = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
    local data = {}
    for line in input:lines() do
        local key, value = string.match(line, PATTERN)
        data[key] = value
    end
    return data
end

local function main(argc, argv)
    if (argc < 1) then
        eprintf("Filename expected from command line\n")
        os.exit(1)
    end

    local data = make_table_from_file(argv[1])
    for k, v in pairs(data) do
        printf("data[%s] = %s\n", k, data[k])
    end

    return 0
end
main(#arg, arg)
```

The variable declared at the top of the file, `PATTERN`, is your capture pattern to be used by `string.match`. If you are unfamiliar with how Lua's pattern matching works, this pattern looks for a series of non-space characters with zero or one spaces to its right, an equal sign, another space, and then another series of non-space characters. The two series of non-space characters are the two matches--`key` and `value`--returned by `string.match` in the function `make_table_from_file`.

The functions `eprintf` and `printf` are my Lua versions of C-style formatted output functions. The former writes to standard error, `io.stderr` in Lua; and the latter writes to standard output, `io.stdout` in Lua.

In your question, you give a sample of what your expected output is. Within your table `data`, you want it to contain keys that correspond to tables as values. Based on the sample input text you provided, I assume the data contained within these tables are whatever comes to the right of the equal signs in the input file--which you represent with `...`. As I do not know what exactly those `...`s represent, I cannot give you a solid example for how to separate that right-hand data into a table. Depending on what you are looking to do, you could take the second variable returned by `string.match`, which I called `value`, and further separate it using Lua's string pattern matching. It could look something like this:

```
...
local function make_table_from_value(val)
    // Split `val` into distinct elements to form a table with `some_pattern`
    return {string.match(val, some_pattern)}
end

local function make_table_from_file(filename)
    local input = assert(io.open(filename, "r"))
    local data = {}
    for line in input:lines() do
        local key, value = string.match(line, PATTERN)
        data[key] = make_table_from_value(value)
    end
    return data
end
...
```

In `make_table_from_value`, `string.match` will return some number of elements, based on whatever string pattern you provide as its second argument, which you can then use to create a table by enclosing the function call in curly braces. It will be a table that uses numerical indices as keys--rather than strings or some other data type--starting from `1`.

Comment: Thank you for all the effort you put in helping me out with this one. :)